# TMP_InputFile date

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to input date of birth in 1502200 form from tmp_input file but want to display "15-02-2000
check format date month year birth day>31 , month>12, 2010<year<2023

```
private void AgeValueChanged(string s_value)
    {
       
       string snum = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(s_value, @"[^0-9]", string.Empty) ?? string.Empty;
       //now ensure is less than max number count in a US phone number. In this example it's 10 as we don't allow the US country code (leading 1)
       if (snum.Length > 8) snum = snum.Substring(0, 8);
 
       //now format according to custom rules
       if (snum.Length < 2)
       {
           //do nothing
       }
       else if(snum.Length == 2)
       {
           snum = $"{snum}";
       }
       else if (snum.Length <= 4)
       {
           snum = $"{snum.Substring(0, 2)} / {snum.Substring(2, snum.Length - 2)}";
       }
       else
       {
           snum = $"{snum.Substring(0, 2)} / {snum.Substring(2, 2)} / {snum.Substring(4, snum.Length - 4)}";
       }
 
       ageInputField.text = snum;
 
       //Here I just move the caret to the end if we changed the text length. You could write some other behavior if you desired.
       if (snum.Length != s_value.Length)
       {
           ageInputField.ForceLabelUpdate();
           ageInputField.MoveTextEnd(false);
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope I get your question right... (Consider editing it - I have no clue what your sample code has to do with your exact question)

If you want to reformat and validate an input date string like *15022000* do the following:

```csharp
string dateString = "15022000"; //this string can come from your input field eg
    
// create a DateTime object out of your date string
// the "TryParseExact" mathod returns true if the date string is valid and the DateTime object as an out variable 
// the format string "ddMMyyyy" does what the name suggests ... it specifies the format you're providing 
// the CultureInfo.InvariantCulture parameter ensures that the parsing is done using the invariant culture, which is a culture-independent format
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(dateString, "ddMMyyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out date))
{
    // parsing successful
    // the 'date' variable now contains the parsed date (so day and month is certainly within their valid ranges)
    
    // so check the year now
    int year = date.Year;
    if (year >= 2010 && year <= 2023)
    {
        // year is between 2010 and 2023
        string formattedDate = date.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");// format it like dd-MM-yyyy
    }
    else
    {
        // year is not between 2010 and 2023
    }
}
else
{
    // parsing failed
    // handle the error or provide a default value
}
```